# Grails war causes memory leak in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I recently deployed a Grails war-file using tomcat. I then wanted to deploy a new version, I stopped/undeployed the old one and tried to deploy the new version. This was all done using the manager pages.

When I clicked on deploy tomcat gave me an error, something saying that the old version started processes that are not stopped aka daemon threads (if I'm not mistaking?).

I've tried increasing the Xmx and Xms since reading the logs I could see that there was no more free memory and it seems to have solved it.

Why does this happen? One would think deploying via the web-interface would be the safest way of doing it, and that all previous processes would be shut down.

How can I avoid getting into this situation in the future?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem. There is no working solution for the web manager re-deployment problem. Try to migrate Grails to the current version.